# How to disable the integrated intel gpu?

Tags: power-management, intel, intel-graphics, gpu

I am operating a headless server and like to **disable the integrated intel hd gpu** in the systems Intel Core i5-7400T CPU to reduce power consumption.

I cannot disable the GPU via BIOS, there is only the option to disable the integrated gpu once a dedicated gpu is detected.

Is there a way I can do this during boot or from within linux?

Alternatively, are there any **power saving options**, if a full disabling is not possible?

I assume that simply **unloading the kernel driver does not shut down the gpu** but rather leaves it in an unused, yet powered on state.